# Is it legal to deny service if I do not provide address?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, consumer-protection

In the UK almost every business will ask for your postcode and house number. For instance, two of the larger real-estate agencies in London refused to register me in their systems unless full and exact current address is provided which in fact prevents me from updates on new housing opportunities. Just to be clear I visited the branch, this is not an online form or a phone conversation.

When I challenged them on the subject they claimed that it has to do with fraud prevention. While it is quite clear that the only fraud is the real-estate agency this is not only this market that does that.

Is it legal for businesses to deny service to customers who do not wish to share their location?

Comment: [IXL](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/414/dealing-with-is-x-illegal-questions)?

Answer (score 4):

Businesses can discriminate against their customers on any basis they like provided that such discrimination is not on an illegal basis like race, sex or age.

They do not have to serve you if they don't want to.